# Избежание повторений в словаре

Tags: python, словарь, повторы

```
result = {}
sort_dictionary = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in dict.items()} for line in data.split('\n'):
name, hobby = line.split(":")
result.setdefault(hobby, []).append(name)
result = sort_dictionary(result)
return result
```

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы в result не было повторений.

```
sample_data = """Jack:crafting\nPeter:hiking\nWendy:gaming\nMonica:tennis\nChris:origami\nSophie:sport\nMonica:design\nCarmen:sport\nChris:sport\nMonica:skateboarding\nCarmen:cooking\nWendy:photography\nMonica:tennis\nCooper:yoga\nWendy:sport\nCooper:movies\nMonica:theatre\nCooper:yoga\nChris:gaming\nMolly:fishing\nJack:skateboarding\nWendy:fishing\nJack:drawing\nMonica:baking\nSophie:baking\nAlfred:driving\nAlfred:shopping\nAlfred:crafting\nJack:drawing\nCarmen:shopping\nCarmen:driving\nPeter:drawing\nCarmen:shopping\nWendy:fitness\nAlfred:travel\nJack:origami\nSophie:design\nJack:pets\nCarmen:dance\nAlfred:baking\nSophie:sport\nPeter:gaming\nJack:skateboarding\nCooper:football\nAlfred:sport\nCooper:fitness\nChris:yoga\nWendy:football\nMolly:design\nJack:hiking\nMonica:pets\nCarmen:photography\nJack:baking\nPeter:driving\nChris:driving\nCarmen:driving\nPeter:theatre\nMolly:hiking\nWendy:puzzles\nJack:crafting\nPeter:photography\nCarmen:theatre\nSophie:crafting\nCarmen:cooking\nAlfred:gaming\nPeter:theatre\nCooper:hiking\nChris:football\nChris:pets\nJack:football\nMonica:skateboarding\nChris:driving\nCarmen:pets\nCooper:gaming\nChris:hiking\nJack:cooking\nPeter:fishing\nJack:gaming\nPeter:origami\nCarmen:movies\nSophie:driving\nJack:sport\nCarmen:theatre\nWendy:shopping\nCarmen:pets\nWendy:gaming\nSophie:football\nWendy:theatre\nCarmen:football\nMolly:theatre\nPeter:theatre\nMonica:flowers\nMolly:skateboarding\nPeter:driving\nSophie:travel\nMonica:photography\nCooper:cooking\nJack:fitness\nPeter:cooking\nChris:gaming"""
```

Должно получится

```json
{
  'crafting': [
    'Alfred',
    'Jack',
    'Sophie'
  ],
  'hiking': [
    'Chris',
    'Cooper',
    'Jack',
    'Molly',
    'Peter'
  ],
  'gaming': [
    'Alfred',
    'Chris',
    'Cooper',
    'Jack',
    'Peter',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'tennis': [
    'Monica'
  ],
  'origami': [
    'Chris',
    'Jack',
    'Peter'
  ],
  'sport': [
    'Alfred',
    'Carmen',
    'Chris',
    'Jack',
    'Sophie',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'design': [
    'Molly',
    'Monica',
    'Sophie'
  ],
  'skateboarding': [
    'Jack',
    'Molly',
    'Monica'
  ],
  'cooking': [
    'Carmen',
    'Cooper',
    'Jack',
    'Peter'
  ],
  'photography': [
    'Carmen',
    'Monica',
    'Peter',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'yoga': [
    'Chris',
    'Cooper'
  ],
  'movies': [
    'Carmen',
    'Cooper'
  ],
  'theatre': [
    'Carmen',
    'Molly',
    'Monica',
    'Peter',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'fishing': [
    'Molly',
    'Peter',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'drawing': [
    'Jack',
    'Peter'
  ],
  'baking': [
    'Alfred',
    'Jack',
    'Monica',
    'Sophie'
  ],
  'driving': [
    'Alfred',
    'Carmen',
    'Chris',
    'Peter',
    'Sophie'
  ],
  'shopping': [
    'Alfred',
    'Carmen',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'fitness': [
    'Cooper',
    'Jack',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'travel': [
    'Alfred',
    'Sophie'
  ],
  'pets': [
    'Carmen',
    'Chris',
    'Jack',
    'Monica'
  ],
  'dance': [
    'Carmen'
  ],
  'football': [
    'Carmen',
    'Chris',
    'Cooper',
    'Jack',
    'Sophie',
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'puzzles': [
    'Wendy'
  ],
  'flowers': [
    'Monica'
  ]
}
```

Comment: добавть желаемый и текущий результаты. Сейчас вопрос выглядит как "угадайте, что мне надо". В словарях повторений и так нет в силу сути словаря.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом setdefault:

```
res = {}
for pair in sample_data.split("\n"):
    value, key = pair.split(":")
    res.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
    
print(res)
```

res:

> {'crafting': ['Jack', 'Alfred', 'Jack', 'Sophie'], 'hiking': ['Peter', 'Jack', 'Molly', 'Cooper', 'Chris'], 'gaming': ['Wendy', 'Chris', 'Peter', 'Alfred', 'Cooper', 'Jack', 'Wendy', 'Chris'], 'tennis': ['Monica', 'Monica'], 'origami': ['Chris', 'Jack', 'Peter'], 'sport': ['Sophie', 'Carmen', 'Chris', 'Wendy', 'Sophie', 'Alfred', 'Jack'], 'design': ['Monica', 'Sophie', 'Molly'], 'skateboarding': ['Monica', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Monica', 'Molly'], 'cooking': ['Carmen', 'Carmen', 'Jack', 'Cooper', 'Peter'], 'photography': ['Wendy', 'Carmen', 'Peter', 'Monica'], 'yoga': ['Cooper', 'Cooper', 'Chris'], 'movies': ['Cooper', 'Carmen'], 'theatre': ['Monica', 'Peter', 'Carmen', 'Peter', 'Carmen', 'Wendy', 'Molly', 'Peter'], 'fishing': ['Molly', 'Wendy', 'Peter'], 'drawing': ['Jack', 'Jack', 'Peter'], 'baking': ['Monica', 'Sophie', 'Alfred', 'Jack'], 'driving': ['Alfred', 'Carmen', 'Peter', 'Chris', 'Carmen', 'Chris', 'Sophie', 'Peter'], 'shopping': ['Alfred', 'Carmen', 'Carmen', 'Wendy'], 'fitness': ['Wendy', 'Cooper', 'Jack'], 'travel': ['Alfred', 'Sophie'], 'pets': ['Jack', 'Monica', 'Chris', 'Carmen', 'Carmen'], 'dance': ['Carmen'], 'football': ['Cooper', 'Wendy', 'Chris', 'Jack', 'Sophie', 'Carmen'], 'puzzles': ['Wendy'], 'flowers': ['Monica']}